# i am trying to split a full name to first middle and last name in pandas but i am stuck at replace

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

i am trying to break the name into two parts and keeping first name last name and finally replacing the common part in all of them such that first name is must then last name then if middle name remain it is added to column

```
df['owner1_first_name'] = df['owner1_name'].str.split().str[0].astype(str, 
errors='ignore')
df['owner1_last_name'] = 
df['owner1_name'].str.split().str[-1].str.replace(df['owner1_first_name'], 
"").astype(str, errors='ignore')
['owner1_middle_name'] = 
df['owner1_name'].str.replace(df['owner1_first_name'], 
"").str.replace(df['owner1_last_name'], "").astype(str, errors='ignore')
```

the problem is i am not able to use 
    .str.replace(df['owner1_name'], "")
as  i am getting an error 
    "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

is there any replacement sytax in pandas for what i am tryin to achieve

my desired output is

full name = THOMAS MARY D which is in column owner1_name

I want

```
owner1_first_name = THOMAS
owner1_middle_name = MARY
owner1_last_name = D
```

Comment: Can you add data sample - 3,4 rows and desired output?

Comment: i want replacement sytax for 'column1 = column2.replace(column3, "")' in pandas

Comment: I can't make sense of what you mean.  Why are you trying to 'replace' columns and what are you trying to replace them with?  Why not add columns and drop the ones you don't want anymore?

Comment: if full name = marry             then as per the code my last name would be same as first name. so i want to replace common in last name and first name with nothing.

Comment: @SandeepKumar - Is my answer what you need?

Comment: @jezrael your answer is very near to what i am trying to achieve but it will work only if whole string matches but what if i want to replace only that part which i common in both columns

Comment: >>> str = "wikipedia is king"
>>> name = "wikipedia"
>>> str.replace(name, "")
' is king'

Comment: @jezrael here i want the above operation (just previous comment) on two columns of a dataframe of pandas

Comment: @jezrael when i try df['col'].str.replace(df['col2'], "") it gives an error that series object is not hashable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) which replace if same values in both columns to empty strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'owner1_name':['THOMAS MARY D', 'JOE Long', 'MARY Small']})

splitted = df['owner1_name'].str.split()
df['owner1_first_name'] = splitted.str[0]
df['owner1_last_name'] = splitted.str[-1]
df['owner1_middle_name'] = splitted.str[1]
df['owner1_middle_name'] = df['owner1_middle_name']
                             .mask(df['owner1_middle_name'] == df['owner1_last_name'], '')
print (df)
     owner1_name owner1_first_name owner1_last_name owner1_middle_name
0  THOMAS MARY D            THOMAS                D               MARY
1       JOE Long               JOE             Long                   
2     MARY Small              MARY            Small
```

What is same as:

```
splitted = df['owner1_name'].str.split()
df['owner1_first_name'] = splitted.str[0]
df['owner1_last_name'] = splitted.str[-1]
middle = splitted.str[1] 
df['owner1_middle_name'] = middle.mask(middle == df['owner1_last_name'], '')
print (df)
     owner1_name owner1_first_name owner1_last_name owner1_middle_name
0  THOMAS MARY D            THOMAS                D               MARY
1       JOE Long               JOE             Long                   
2     MARY Small              MARY            Small
```

EDIT:

For `replace` by rows is possible use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'owner1_name':['THOMAS MARY-THOMAS', 'JOE LongJOE', 'MARY Small']})

splitted = df['owner1_name'].str.split()
df['a'] = splitted.str[0]
df['b'] = splitted.str[-1]

df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b'].replace(x['a'], ''), axis=1)
print (df)
          owner1_name       a            b      c
0  THOMAS MARY-THOMAS  THOMAS  MARY-THOMAS  MARY-
1         JOE LongJOE     JOE      LongJOE   Long
2          MARY Small    MARY        Small  Small
```

the exact code to in three line to achieve what i wanted in my question is

```
df['owner1_first_name'] = df['owner1_name'].str.split().str[0]
df['owner1_last_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['owner1_name'].split()
[-1].replace(x['owner1_first_name'], ''), axis=1)
df['owner1_middle_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
x['owner1_name'].replace(x['owner1_first_name'], 
'').replace(x['owner1_last_name'], ''), axis=1)
```

Comment: after spliting i want to remove the common part in all the three columns when i try df['owner1_last_name'].str.replace(df['owner1_first_name'], "") it gives an error that series object is not hashable. i want to do so because my data is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

Just change your assignment and use another variable:

```
split = df['owner1_name'].split()
df['owner1_first_name'] = split[0]
df['owner1_middle_name'] = split[-1]
df['owner1_last_name'] = split[1]
```

Comment: after spliting i want to remove the common part in all the three columns when i try df['owner1_last_name'].str.replace(df['owner1_first_name'], "") it gives an error that series object is not hashable. i want to do so because my data is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

```
splitted = df['Contact_Name'].str.split()
df['First_Name'] = splitted.str[0]
df['Last_Name'] = splitted.str[-1]
df['Middle_Name'] = df['Contact_Name'].loc[df['Contact_Name'].str.split().str.len() == 3].str.split(expand=True)[1]
```

This might help! the part here is to rightly insert the middle name which you can do by this code..

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `extract` parameter. It will return a new dataframe with columns named 0, 1, 2. You can rename them in one line:

```py
col_names = ['owner1_first_name', 'owner1_middle_name', 'owner1_last_name']
df.owner1_name.str.split(extract=True).rename(dict(range(len(col_names), col_names)))
```

Beware that this code breaks if someone has four names. Better to it in 2 steps: `split(n=1, extract=True)` and then `rsplit(n=1, extract=True`